# Does flagging an email store that information locally or on the mailserver?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, big-sur

Do emails I flag on macOS Mail.app also get flagged on whichever email provider I am using?

Can I safely uninstall and reinstall Mail.app, and recreate all my internet accounts, without losing information such as which emails I have flagged?

Comment: POP or IMAP?...

Comment: @Tetsujin Exchange, Exchange, and IMAP